fsutil file queryFileNameById on Network Drive
I have a network drive (L:), which is an NTFS volume, and I'm using fsutil to get a unique identifier of a file as follows:
PS L:\> fsutil file queryFileID .\Pictures\
File ID is 0x0000000001240041

and it seems to work. But when I try to get the file name for this ID I get an error:
PS L:\> fsutil file queryFileNameById 'L:' '0x0000000001240041'
Error:  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

This method works fine on a local drive:
PS C:\> fsutil file queryFileID .\temp\
File ID is 0x0000000000000000008b00000006eb50
PS C:\> fsutil file queryFileNameById 'C:' '0x0000000000000000008b00000006eb50'
A random link name to this file is \\?\C:\temp

I assume that the "volume label syntax is incorrect", as the error message implies. I also tried using the UNC path as the volume but I received the same error:
PS L:\> fsutil file queryFileNameById \\192.168.xxx.xxx\xxx '0x0000000001240041'
Error:  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

What is the volume label syntax for a network drive? Or is it a different issue?
